# JavaScript flatMap() error: "flatMap mapper function is not callable"

Tags: javascript, flatten

I am trying to flatten an array with the following code, but when I use `.flatMap()` I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: flatMap mapper function is not callable
    at Array.flatMap (<anonymous>)
```

```
const data = [
        { key1: 5, key3: 2 },
        { key1: 2, key3: 1 },
        { key1: 3, key3: 2 },
        { key2: 8 },
        { key1: 5, key3: 2 },
      ];
var allKeys = data.map(r => Object.keys(r))
// [
//   [ 'key1', 'key3' ],
//   [ 'key1', 'key3' ],
//   [ 'key1', 'key3' ],
//   [ 'key2' ],
//   [ 'key1', 'key3' ]
// ]
allKeys.flatMap();
```

Comment: because flatMap require function as parameter. Just use `flat()`

Comment: Have you read `flatMap` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I should be using `flat()` not `flatMap()`. The below works as expected.

```js
const data = [
    { key1: 5, key3: 2 },
    { key1: 2, key3: 1 },
    { key1: 3, key3: 2 },
    { key2: 8 },
    { key1: 5, key3: 2 },
];
var allKeys = data.map(r => Object.keys(r))
console.log(allKeys.flat());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `map` to be more concise, which eliminates the need for calling `.flat()` after, as it is just shorthand for `.map(...).flat()`. As well, you can directly pass `Object.keys` as the callback for `flatMap`, as it ignores all arguments other than the first one that it is given.

```js
const data = [
        { key1: 5, key3: 2 },
        { key1: 2, key3: 1 },
        { key1: 3, key3: 2 },
        { key2: 8 },
        { key1: 5, key3: 2 },
      ];
var allKeys = data.flatMap(Object.keys)
console.log(allKeys);
```